# CSS Media Query does not apply on exact 767

Tags: css, media-queries

This is my html file.
on browser width 769 background color of the body is White.
on 768 it changes to Green.
on 767 I am expecting it to become Red but it still remains green.
on 766 It becomes red.
So my confusion is why does media query does not apply when screen size is exact 767.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asifsomy/wtvknrja/3/show

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this on Chrome on Windows10 dev tools and it works fine - the body is showing as red on width 767. What are you using to test it?

Comment: I tried on Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: That’s weird that we see different things. How are you setting the exact width? I’m using the responsive ‘device’ on Chrome dev tools. What happens if you try 766.99?

Comment: I added a screenshot for. I am doing the same thing. Cant change width to 766.999 though.

Answer (score 0):

it could be an issue with your BROWSER ZOOM.. make sure it is at 100%, cause it is at 110%, this will make your media query trigger at different PX

broswer settings -> zoom -> 100%

Answer (score -1):

By default background color is white. You use max-width that's why background-color show green only for 768px. When your screen size greater then that it's got white default color. If you want green color when screen size greater then 768px just use **min-width**

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Screen size 767px body color
https://prnt.sc/10hrmna